# Clearing the python IDLE screen in win7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Any way we can add configuration to python IDLE and assign it a shortcut, so when we use the shortcut a function call to clear the python IDLE screen? like print '\n' * 50, just to make a shortcut to clear the python IDLE. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: How can it be a duplicate? The answer to that question is embedded in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can `import os` and try `os.system('clear')` to clear the screen rather than printing multiple `\n`'s. For Windows it would look like `os.system('CLS')` as the commented (above) link suggests.

Comment: os.system('CLS') does not work in IDLE on my Windows 7 system...

Comment: It doesn't work on my windows 7 and I am trying to make it a shortcut. Like if you press CTRL+L, your python IDLE on windows 7 will get clear.

Comment: It works, but only when you run the py directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option might be using something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

An example for making a ctrl-r hotkey that would do what your asking with AutoHotKey is:

```
^r::SendInput print '\n' * 50 {Enter}
```

Just install AutoHotKey, put the above in a file called idle_clear.ahk, run the file, and your hotkey is active.